# Reset position when using position:fixed

Tags: html, css, css-position

I want to make a website where the (dynamic in height) header and footer have a fixed position. The content should start directly beneath the header. I made a quick [example](http://www.braemhof.be/fixed.html). (Yellow and red top positions are the same, I want the yellow DIV to start beneath the red DIV.)

If you set the header position to fixed, the content DIV is placed at the same top position of the header.

For example, if you use float, you can use clear: both to reset the position, is there also a possibility for position: fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**CSS Only Solution**

Use some way to pad the space the header takes up at the top of the screen:

- `padding-top:`
- `margin-top:`
- `position:relative + top:`

Then have a separate CSS style sheet to change `height` for regular `viewport`s versus mobile `viewport`s.

*(Or see below for JavaScript solution to set the `height` attribute dynamically.)*

- [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t7qMc/1/)

HTML:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="header">
      Header
    </div>
    <div id="wrapper">
      <p>First Row</p>
      <p>Next row</p>
      <p>...</p>
      <p>Last row</p>
    <div>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS (regular version):

```
#header {
  position:fixed;
  height:100px;
  width:100%;
  background-color:green;
  color:white;
}
#wrapper {
  position:relative;
  top:101px;
}
```

CSS (mobile version):

```
#header {
  height:50px;
}
#wrapper {
  top:51px;
}
```

---

**JavaScript Solution**

HTML *(copy-and-paste-able)*:

```
<head>
  <style>
    #header {
      position:fixed;
      height:100px; /* try different values here! */
      width:100%;
      background-color:green;
      color:white;
    }
    #wrapper {
      position:relative; /* look Mom no height! */
    }
  </style>
</head>
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="header">
      Header
    </div>
    <div id="wrapper">
      <p>First Row</p>
      <p>Next row</p>
      <p>...</p>
      <p>Last row</p>
    <div>
    <script language="javascript">
      document.getElementById('wrapper').style.top = String(document.getElementById("header").offsetHeight + 1);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It seems that what I want (with a header that's dynamic in height) the only way is to set a height, or to use margin together with jQuery to get the height of the header.

Comment: Hmm, never heard of jsFiddle, nice application!

Comment: Your answer works great for a header with a fixed height... But the height of my header can change. So I'll have to use javascript to get the height. Thanks anyway!

Comment: You can do that, or have a separate CSS for mobile devices.

Comment: I have to say, this answer is clear, and very well documented... Thanks, I will use your answer!

Comment: I already have seperate CSS for mobile. I'm using the Omega template for Drupal.

Comment: *Your welcome.* Please see new edit for the JavaScript solution that you were interested in as well.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old post, but have recently come across this issue myself. So just thought I would share my solution (although I haven't fully tested it yet - add disclaimer here).

I created another container (div) below the fixed one (top of page), with the same settings, class etc and content.

Then I added a style to reset this second div to position:static, visibility:hidden.  You don't really need to hide it, as it is completely covered by the fixed div; but just in case it's an older browser which doesn't recognise position:fixed.

Anyway this will give you a buffer area above your content that should always be the correct height.  Downside is that if there is dynamic content then this will be included twice in your page for this area, but you need that content to make sure the hidden div is the right height.

Not a perfect solution, but the best I can come up with ... bar using javascript.

Answer (score 0):

use z-index (css)
for one div make it: z-index:-1;
for other z-index:1;

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp

Comment: z-index just changes what DIV is at top and what DIV is at the bottom... But that's not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is to add a margin-top that's equal to the height of your header. Do the same for margin-bottom to accommodate the footer.

Comment: That was my first idea, but when you don't know the header height you cannot use this idea... I'm using a Drupal template that changes the layout for mobile, small and big screens...

Comment: I see, you should say you have a dynamic header in your question then. You could use jquery (javascript) to find the height of the header and footer then make those values the margin-top and margin-bottom.

Comment: Changed the question. The header is indeed dynamic in height. You don't think this is feasable with CSS only?

Comment: No, you'd have to use javascript. Why do you not want to use it?

Comment: If there would be a CSS solution it wouldn't be smart to use jQuery, but if there is no other way I don't mind using it, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `padding-top` and `padding-bottom`. In your example, if you add `padding-top: 25px;` to the style, it will display under the top fixed div.

As you know, a fixed position shows in the same spot on the browser and doesn't move as you scroll. The rest of the "normal" content is not affected by fixed positioned elements, so you have to use padding and margin to create some buffer space.

Comment: See comment above... When you make the window smaller, the height of the header DIV changes, so... you don't know the height.

Comment: You can assign a `width` or a `height` to your fixed DIV to prevent it from dynamically changing sizes.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <body>

   <div style="background-color: red; position: fixed;width:100%;">This is a test with position set  to fixed</div>
  <div style="background-color: yellow; height: 1000px;">This is content that should  start beneath the fixed DIV</div>

    </body>
```